# $\textbf Z[\omega]$ is UFD for $\omega$ being $p-$th root of unity where $3 < p < 23$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

This is an assumption made in Marcus, Number Fields.

$\textbf Z[\omega]$ is UFD for $\omega$ $p-$th root of unity with $3 < p < 23$.

For $p = 2, 3$, one can use Neukrich geometric proof on the distance to the nearest lattice point. It seems that this proof fails for $p=5$ as there are lattice points which is not generated by shifting the fundamental lattice $0,\omega,i\omega,(1+i)\omega$.

Q: Was there a unified approach to deal with this problem for $3 < p < 23$?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to compute Minkowski's bound and factor all primes below it into prime ideals. If all of them are principal, the number ring is a UFD (note that this still forces you to do separate calculations for each $p$). If you keep reading Marcus' book, you will learn more about this approach.

Comment: This is a very minor detail which I could be wrong about: shouldn't that say "$p$-th root" instead of $p-$th root"?